# How do I add text in this loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry Im just a begginer,

So I have this game being modified and the game output so far looks like this
[image]
The score is in the bottom, the one I encircled

I wanted to add a name to it

So far I just discovered how it was made, apparently, the creator made a loop wherein, for every player,there would be a score for them
here's the code named scoreboard.js

```
    constructor(players) {
        this.scores = {};

        let scorePosition = 200; // this changes the position of the scores in width

        for (const player of players) {
            console.log(player.name);//////////shows the player name in console 

            this.scores[player.name] = new Score(createVector(scorePosition, config.screen.height + 50));

            //originally;
            // this.scores[player.name] = new Score(createVector(scorePosition, config.screen.height + 50)); 

            //replacing "config.screen.height" will change the height of scoreboard but in absolute position 
            scorePosition += 200; //this sets the distance of between space of scores
        }
    }

    reset() {
        for (const score in this.scores) {
            this.scores[score].value = 0;
        }
    }

    draw() {
        for (const score in this.scores) {
            this.scores[score].draw();
        }
    }
}
```

I added `console.log(player.name);` to the loop and this happens
[image]
As you can see, it writes the player's name (Player1,Player2,etc.)

The problem how do I get to write it next to their score?

Im sure there's supposed to be a code that I should put inside of that for loop instead of console.log

I tried `document.write()` or `document.writeIn()`
but I'm pretty sure that won't work
[image]
And Im sort of right

Ps.here is the code named score.js, it has connection to scoreboard.js
I'm not sure if this information is helpful so I'll leave it here

```
class Score extends SpriteEntity {
    constructor(position) {
        super({
            position,

            sprites: [...Array(10).keys()].map(index => index.toString()),
            imageSetup: image => image.resize(100, 100) //this changes the size of the box
        });

        this.value = 8;
        //this is initial value of the score
    }
    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(value) {
        this._value = value;
        this.sprite.changeImage(this.value);
    } //this replaces the number according to its score

    increment() {

        ++this.value;
    }

}
```

Another ps: If you're wondering, the score is just an image named 0-9 .png
[image]

Comment: modify the DOM at the place the scores are displayed, add a new container, give it an ID and then fill in the names there. you should first understand HTML, CSS and JS basics to hope to get into the nitty gritty of a project as complex as your game seems to be ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could this. You could use HTML+CSS like this:

```
<style>
#playernames {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#playernames > div {
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px; /* Change this to the score width */
  text-align: center;
  font: 14px Tahoma;
  color: blue;
}
</style>
<div id="playernames"></div>
```

And change the content with:

```
var playernames = "";
for (const player of players) {
  playernames += "<div>" + 
    player.name.replace(/[&<>"]/g, "") + // Strip Html sensitive characters
    "</div>";
  ...
}
document.getElementById("playernames").innerHTML = playernames;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It did work, but I forgot to mention the html body's display is flex and justify-content to center

I had to adjust it a bit by adding position absolute
`#playernames {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}`
like this since the player name was written at the top

Thanks to you I can finally rest in peace xD